# Why won't a 5x5 multiplication array appear?

Tags: c, arrays

I did this and I think it should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j;

   for(i=1;i<=5;i++);
   {
       for(j=1;j<=5;j++);
       {
           printf("%d",i*j);
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But it just prints out `36`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 7):

Remove the two extra `;`s:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++);
                 ^
{
   for(j=1;j<=5;j++);
                    ^
```

Comment: Even if he does that it'll output something like
123452468103691215
which is going to be less than readable

Comment: @TomTanner Yes, I know. I would rather leave such job to OP to figure it out. :P

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the semicolons before the opening braces of your for loops are preventing the printing.

Additionally, if you want the output to appear as a matrix, you'll want to printf a newline after your first for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j;

   for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
   {
       for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
       {
           printf("%d",i*j);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```